# Python tkinter: How do I 'send' to a tkname that has spaces in it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to send() a tk message to an existing tcl/tk compatible running program.

Problem is that this running program has a space in its tk name.  Think "bob #2".

For the life of me I can't figure out how to send() to "bob #2" and have it work.

This is the most common error I get:
_tkinter.TclError: Wrong number of args for "MyCmd"

## simplified version of my code

```
tname = 'bob #2'
mw.send(tName, "MyCmd")
```

Any ideas?  -thx

Comment: Post some code of what you have tried and what lines are giving you the error.

Comment: The error looks more like you're missing some parameters for the command that you're trying to send. What is "MyCmd" exactly?

Comment: It is not due to missing some parameter for the command.  It works fine so long as the tkname has no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: completely untested!*

Have you tried

```
tname = '{bob #2}'
mw.send(tName, "MyCmd")
```

You shouldn't have to do that if the `send` method had been written properly.  The curly braces would be Tcl solution to the problem (of a badly written `send` method).  Another possible solution might be:

```
tname = 'bob\ #2'
```

Or, perhaps a `\\`.